# Apache Virtual Host isn't Serving Virtual Host 'index.html' at Domain Name

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

[image: This is the html file I want to serve at my domain name]

[image: This is output from diagnostic commands]

[image: More diagnostic output]

[image: Screen Shot of my Domain '.conf' File]

[image: Terminal Screen]

When I go to my ip address an index file is served.
However when I navigate to my domain name a page isn't served.
Apache won't serve content from my (domain name) web directory.

I don't plan to install PHP or a Database until the virtual hosts implementation is legit.

[image: I want my index.html to be served when I navigate to the domain name]

[image: Apache is serving content when I navigate to the ip address]

I've reinstalled my image more times than I can count to get my websites migrated to a virtual server.  The biggest sticking point is configuring the virtual hosts. My latest attempt was using this blog article:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-apache-with-virtual-hosts-on-debian-10/

Before that it was this article in previous attempts:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mariadb-php-lamp-stack-on-debian-10

I looked at this article too:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-debian-10/

I saw mentions of a user called www-data during my internet search but it isn't mentioned in the three blog posts I cited.

My hosting company keeps telling me to use Plesk but they didn't configure the shared hosting environment for the migration extension.
So I can't use Plesk to migrate and they charge me a monthly fee for the Plesk license if it is installed on the image.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-access.log combined
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not the correct answer, but I went into my file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`
and changed the lines from:

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
<VirtualHost *:8888>
 #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 DocumentRoot /home/MyPath/Drives/02000/www
```

Comment: That's a cool work around @Bryan.  Unfortunately I disabled the default site because I plan to host more than one web site.

Comment: this guide looks a little better. https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-the-ubuntu-operating-system/

Comment: It looks like a good read @Bryan!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the domain name in other browsers and Chrome is forcing HTTPS at my request.  I didn't get around to reinstalling the SSL/TLS because of the confusion with the virtual hosts.  So basically the page has been live the entire time but Chrome wouldn't connect because a secure connection was unavailable.